# How do I merge asset catalogs

Tags: ios, asset-catalog

I have separate assets for 2 targets in the project Foo and Bar.
Now a single target can switch mode and act as either
one of the targets, changing target memberships brings a ton of warnings

```
FooAssets.xcassets: The image set name "baz" is used by multiple image sets.
```

Is there an automated way to merge assets from Bar into Foo
if they are not present in Foo?

tnx